# Why __metaclass__ doesn't work?

Tags: python, django

After reading parts of Django source code, I want to do some test and write codes below to watch how **metaclass** works:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print cls, name, bases, attrs
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class AttrFiled(object): pass

class Test(MyMeta):
    name = AttrField()
```

It always complains:

```
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

And I add modify it as below:

```
def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):  # copied from Django code.
    return meta("NewBase", bases, {})

class Test(with_metaclass(MyMeta)):
    name = CharField()
```

and it works.

I also read this [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).
But still feel confused.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`with_metaclass` was first introduced in the `six` library (if I recall correctly), that eases transition from Python 2 to Python 3. It's a clever trick to make code compatible with both of them.

Python 2 has the following syntax for declaring use of metaclass:

```
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
```

Python 3, has a different one:

```
class Foo(metaclass=FooMeta):
    pass
```

What `with_metaclass(meta)` does: it creates an intermediate temporary class using `meta` metaclass' constructor directly, and you derive your class from it. So both Pythons -- 2 and 3 are happy.

You should also read Python documentation on this topic: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses

---

In your specific case, when you write `class Test(MyMeta):` you're just declaring a **metaclass** `Test` that is derived from `MyMeta`. To make a **class**, you need to write either

```
 class Test:
     __metaclass__ = MyMeta
```

or

```
 class Test(metaclass=MyMeta):
     ...
```

depending on what python version you have.  Or, if you are not sure if you need to support Python 2 or not, you can simply use `with_metaclass`, it's also OK.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful. BTW, why is it named with six.py ? 2*3 ? :)

Comment: Quoting six' official documentation: "The name, “six”, comes from the fact that 2*3 equals 6. Why not addition? Multiplication is more powerful, and, anyway, “five” has already been snatched away by the Zope Five project." ;)